# external jar NoClassDefFoundError. Order and Export method doesn't work

Tags: android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I'm using several external jar in my android project. But I've got the following the error when running:

**06-06 11:54:17.500: E/AndroidRuntime(3463): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.neuroph.nnet.MultiLayerPerceptron**

The error is caused by the failure to find neuroph-core-2.7.jar. The way I add this external jar is by simply copying it into "libs" folder.

I'm using ADT version 22.0.1. The answer to other similar questions saying select the android private libraries in "order and export" will work. I did so, but it is not working.
So in my "order and export", I've selected android private libraries:

[image]

Also I put my external jars in "libs" folder:
[image]

Anyone helps please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Solved. The error is actually caused by the external jar itself. The jar used jre1.7 instead of 1.6 and some classes(swing) which android didn't support.