# Neuroph:external jar NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, neural-network

Now im trying to develop an android app using neuroph , i read on the forums but didnt find the about the error im getting .The error is caused by the failure to find neuroph-core-2.7.jar. The way I add this external jar is by simply copying it into "libs" folder.
Im getting this error
E/AndroidRuntime(442): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork
I read this post [external jar NoClassDefFoundError. Order and Export method doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968073/external-jar-noclassdeffounderror-order-and-export-method-doesnt-work) but I did not understand what did he do exactly to solve the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g7ut.jpg

Comment: did you check that jar file in `Order & Export` tab in Eclipse?

Comment: I cheked and I find it .